# How to save the positions of random numbers using Shuf command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Below is my `shuf` command.

```
shuf -i 1-5
```

How we can save the positions of random numbers? How we can check my previous generated random number? I need only unique random number in shell script?How we can do this any help?

Comment: Don't know about shell scripts much but common logic dictates that you would first have to keep a record of already generated numbers somewhere  and based on that you can compare your newly generated numbers, deciding whether to keep them (them being unique) or discard them (Them being already present in your list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550372/generate-non-repeating-random-number-sequences-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. Man page of `shuf` starts:

```
shuf - generate random permutations
```

Random **permutations**. Means that it won't have any duplicates. So if you want to have 20 random, unique numbers between 1 and 100, use

```
$ shuf -i 1-100 -n 20
```

You can even sort them:

```
$ shuf -i 1-100 -n 20 | sort
```

Comment: You'd think that the man page would explicitly state that there are no duplicates, not everyone knows the finer points of the definition of "permutation." But `shuf -i 1-10 -n 20 | sort` only outputs 10 numbers, looks good

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shuf` to generate as many unique random numbers as you want (up to the range of the numbers, obviously), but you need to generate them all at once.

For example, you can generate a complete shuffle of all 100 numbers between 1 and 100, and keep them in a bash array:

```
numbers=($(shuf -i1-100))
```

Then you can just extract a new number from the array each time you need one.

```
index=0
# ...
r=${numbers[index++]}
```

Comment: Thanks rici you understood my problem.It solved and it is working.